# React is not re-rendering to reflect the setState

Tags: reactjs

I simply have two textareas. When you input text into the first textarea, the text should appear in the second textarea. I've checked to ensure that the event is firing. The page just doesn't seem to render... Please help, thank you.

```
var OutputText = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      text: ''
    };
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className='text-center'>Markdown Previewer</h1>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-xs-4 text-center'>
            <textarea className='user-input' onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className='col-xs-4 text-center'>
            <textarea>{this.state.text}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(
  <OutputText />,
  document.getElementById('main-container')
);
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in the console? I think React will warn you that you should use `<textarea value={this.state.text} />` instead of what you're doing, which might fix the issue.

Comment: I am currently unable to test, but have you tried `<textarea value={this.state.text} />` instead?

Comment: No warnings but that solved it. Thank you! How can I know what will work/not work with each html tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39872/)

You cannot set the value inside of a `textarea` using react children like that.

You need to add your text as a `value` on the `textarea` tag like so:

```
<textarea value={this.state.text}></textarea>
```

further more, you should use ReactDOM.render, as React.render is deprecated:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <OutputText />,
  document.getElementById('main-container')
);
```

Both of these errors were in the console.